# Installing Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 710 with Signature Edition

Tags: lenovo, raid

I bought Lenovo Yoga 710-15ISK with installed Windows 10 Signature Edition. It turned out that I can't install Ubuntu because of the problem decsribed here:

"Warning: Microsoft Signature PC program now requires that you can't run Linux. Lenovo's recent Ultrabooks among affected systems."
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/53ri0m/warning_microsoft_signature_pc_program_now/

Is Ubuntu going to support RAID mode which was intentionally forced to be used in my laptop model? Or maybe now there exists some workaround?

Pawel

Comment: I would be ranting and raving all over every Lenovo website I could find about this draconian activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help you, for me it's working https://swethmandava16.wordpress.com/2016/10/17/installing-ubuntu-14-04-on-lenovo-yoga-710/